# What is the proper way to include debug msgs in npm packages?

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm

Let's say I have a node package like so:-

```
var debug = require('debug');
debug('starting..');
module.exports = function(){
 debug('printing..');
 return 'Hello World';
};
```

And I include `debug` package as my `devDependencies` and publish my package in `npm`. Now when someone installs my package then obviously `debug` package won't be installed on their end as it's a `devDependencies` so when the user runs my program it's going to throw error as s/he doesn't have that package installed.

Now, technically I could do this:-

```
var debug = process.env.DEBUG ? require('debug') : '';
```

and it'd be fine since the user is specifically trying to debug the program and throwing him/her error is not a problem but what I'd like to know is how do you guys handle this? Just leave `debug` as `dependency` of your app? And is there any other solution to this? Any solution is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using [this](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) debug module, then just leave it in as a dependency. You can see that a few major libraries (such as Express, Socket.IO) do this. One example can be seen [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/package.json#L29).

Comment: :( I was hoping to not include that as dependency as it serves no purpose to the end user unless they really want to tinker with it. Also, yes. That's the module.